# group by for unique values

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, numpy

I currently have a dataframe which looks like below

[image]

I would like to group by based on column 1, so for CONT-1, column 2 should group and provide all 3 addresses, if there are any duplicates, it should avoid.

Currently using this code

```
opt = df.groupby('Temp ID', as_index=True).agg({'PRS_location': lambda x: '\n'.join(np.unique(x))})
```

But for some reason, I am having this below error.

error: TypeError: '<' not supported between instances of 'int' and 'str'

I check if my data have any integers or floats, but none. I do have some empty cells. Could anyone have any idea?